# Updating model with ID of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, foreign-keys

Thought this would be a little straightforward, I may be missing something very simple.  I wanted a dropdown list on the `teams/create` view that let me select the appropriate division for a team, the `id` of which would be placed in the `division_id` column in the `teams` table.

I have two models:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :city, :name
   belongs_to :divison
   has_many :players
end

class Division < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name
   has_many :teams
end
```

and their attendant migrations:

```
create_table :divisions do |t|
  t.string :name

  t.timestamps
end

create_table :teams do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.string :city
  t.integer :division_id

  t.timestamps
end
```

On the view, the dropdown list works as expected:

```
<%= collection_select(:team, :division_id, Division.all, :id, :name) %>
```

However, when I submit the form, the value is not placed in `:division_id`.  Instead, I get a `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: division_id` error.  From the searching I've done, I could remove attr_accessible, but that would present a security flaw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your `attr_accessible` in your `Team` model:

```
attr_accessible :city, :name, :division_id
```

I imagine in your `TeamController` `create` action you are simply calling `Team.new(params[:team])`, which is doing a mass-assignment of attributes. For every attribute you want to support for mass-assignment, you need to declare it in your `attr_accessible`.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something tiny.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly assign value of division_id to the object before save.

```
@team = Team.new(params[:team]) # division_id is not set during mass-assignment
@team.division_id = params[:team][:division_id]
@team.save
```

I think it will solve your problem.